# Does Webpack loader tests run more than once?

Tags: javascript, webpack

In webpack config for loader

```js
[
  {
    test: /\.ext1*$/,
    loader: 'firstLoader',
  },
  {
    test: /\.ext2*$/,
    loader: 'secondLoader'
  }
]
```

If the test for firstLoader matches the file extension, the firstLoader will be loaded, but will the second test be also tested?

I am asking this because for a given file, if somehow a second test also matches (mistake in regex), I wonder if the secondLoader will also be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a loader definition is tested and executed when matched. It is common to have a number of loaders each targeting different file extensions, for example to include CSS or image files in the bundle.